# How to implement stack data structure to range extraction (codewars task)?

Tags: data-structures, stack, range, extract, overlap

I'm struggling with codewars kata called Range Extraction - that it takes a list of integers in increasing order and returns a correctly formatted string in the range format(overlapping seperate intervals).

Example solution:

```
([-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]);
// returns "-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20"
```

Well in my solution, instead of getting `-6,-3-1,3-5,7-11,14,15,17-20`, I got the last item `-6,1,5,11,15,20`.

How can I enhance my solution? The code:

```
function solution(list){
    let result=[]
    for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        let e2=list[i]
        let e1 = result[result.length-1]
        if(e2-e1==1){
            result[result.length-1]=e2
        }
        else{
          result.push(e2 )
        }
    }
    return result
}
console.log(solution([-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]))
```

Comment: By the way, I had to completely reformat your question to even understand what it was talking about. If you want answers, please put even minimal effort into making your question legible.

Comment: please exuse me for , my english is bad i will try my best to clear the question the next time thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing to write consecutive integers in range format. Instead you are just replacing the previous result with the final item in the range which is exactly reflected in your solution:

```
-6: this number has no "neighbors" so is fine
1: the  final item in the first range
5: the final item in the second range
...
```

the problem is the internal logic of the loop.

In summary, you need a while instead of an if and you need to append instead of replace:

```
function solution(list){
    let result=[]

    for(let i=0;i<list.length;i++){
        //write first value in range to result
        result.push(list[i].toString())
        //if this is the last entry, we are done 
        if(i === list.length - 1){
            break
        }
        //initialize variables
        let e1 = list[i]
        let e2 = list[i+1]
        let isRange = false
        //run thorugh array while we get consecutive numbers
        while(e2-e1===1 && i < list.length-1){
            //modify the OUTER LOOP index variable.
            //This means when we return to the beginning of hte for loop,
            // we will be at the beginning of the next range
            i++ 
            e1 = list[i]
            e2 = list[i+1]
            isRange = true
        }
        //if there were any consecutive numbers
        if(isRange){
            //rewrite the last entry in result as a range
            result[result.length-1]+="-" + list[i].toString()
        }
    }
    return result.toString()
}
console.log(solution([-6, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20]))
```

now, your outer loop runs through the entire array once. The inner loop will make sure the outer loop skips any items in the list that appear in a range. Finally, if the inner loop found any range at all, it will rewrite the entry as the correct range.

Comment: thank you so much oh my god i feel my try is totally different i really feel i m lost

Comment: @medazzouzi I'd tried to keep the code as similar to yours as possible, however it is not possible to keep it exactly the same given the nature of the problem. where are you lost?

Comment: thank you so much i love your code so much  i kinda didn't understood why you reassign  e1 and e2 variables inside the while loop and also  this statement if(i === list.length - 1){
            break
        } is it necessary to keep it ?

Comment: honestly not sure - I'm not an expert on javascript. If you do not keep it, then if the last item is not a range then you will wind up setting `let e2 = list[i+1]` which is past the end of the array. In most languages this causes an exception but javascript might make this undefined. Regardless, seems better to be explicit about it - if we are on the last item, do not even check for a range. I did try to run it without the check and it seems to wrok, so feel free to remove. 

Also, if my answer was satisfactory please accept and give me an upvote :)

Comment: Regarding the reassignment of `e1` and `e2` - you need to check whether the next element in the list is part of the range, so you need to reassign `e1` and `e2` once `i` has been incremented. Technically you do not need `e1` and `e2` at all if you use the list explicitly in the while loop condition:
        `while(list[i+1]-list[i]===1 && i < list.length-1)`
but I wanted to mimic your code as much as possible.

Comment: also, it occurs to me, that the second condition in the while loop: `i < list.length-1` is also unnecessary

Comment: thank you so much so much , i love your code and your answer so much thanks for your effort and i appreciat your help , thank you so so so so much <3 i m sorry i m new in this platform xD please how i can support you or give you upvote it said it must at least 15 reputation ? ?